# How to display <p> only once if any of the each conditions are true in rails html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

In my html.erb file:

```
<% @user.relationships.each do |relationship| %>
  <% if relationship.status == "requested" %>
    <p>You have friend requests from: </p> 
    <%= User.find(relationship.followed_id).name %>
```

Problem is I only want to display the

You have friend requests from:

one time if there are ANY matches, whereas currently it does it for each time status == "requested".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to load all objects, lets do this in ruby otherwise this should be done using a scope.

In your model:

```
def requested?
  status == 'requested'
end
```

In your controller:

```
@relationships = @user.relationships.includes(:followed)
@requested_relationships = @relationships.select &:requested?
```

In your view:

```
<% if @requested_relationships.any? %>
  <p>You have friend requests from: </p> 
    <% @requested_relationships.each do |relationship| %>
       <%= relationship.followed.name %>
```

---

Edited to prevent n+1 queries

Comment: That isn't a scope in the [Rails sense](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). A scope would look more like: `scope :requested, -> { where(status: 'requested') }`

Comment: It is still not a scope. When you call `#select` on an ActiveRecord relationship, it loads _every single record_ into memory as an array of ActiveRecord instances. Using a scope like my suggestion above would load the records lazily.

Comment: read my answer again, I explicitly say I do this in ruby since the op seems to want all relationships anyway

Comment: doesnt the <p> line need to be outside the each loop?

Comment: oh, and i think you need to change ser.relationships.each do |relationship| to @requested_relationships.each...   maybe I didn't specify that I want to iterate only over the relationships with status "requested"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<% requested = @user.relationships.where(status: 'requested') %>
<% if requested.any? %>
  <p>You have friend requests from: </p> 
  <% requested.each do |relationship| %>
    <%= User.find(relationship.followed_id).name %>
```

Comment: You should create scopes